# Problems with UTF8 CSV Import in Mathematica 11.2

Tags: import, character-encoding

I have a lot of code for importing csv data from a research project. Everything fine with Mathematica 11.1.1. Now I have 11.2 and it seems as if UTF8 import ist buggy. I use the following simple code to get the data in:

```
file = SystemDialogInput["FileOpen"]
```

and

```
data = Import[file, "CSV", CharacterEncoding -> "UTF8"]
```

with 11.2 I get a lot of error messages (see screenshot) and the German Umlauts are all corrupted. No problems with 11.1.1. Can anyone help or confirm.
[image]

Example Data can be found here: [example](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jhq90d20zuvyhx0/Example.csv?dl=0)

Comment: Can you share a file which we could possible investigate this using?

Comment: Sorry and thank you for the comment, I forgot to place the download link in the text.... just done!

Comment: I am not debating whether there was an issue or not, but I do see the same error messages in 11.1 and 11.2.

Comment: In any event, if you think there is an issue just report it to support@wolfram.com and they can provide more info, etc...

Comment: I get the same with version 8.0.4 on Windows 7 x64. But when I simply do `Import["Example.csv"]` it is imported without errors. The obvious conclusion is that the file is NOT UTF8-encoded.

Comment: This is not a bug in Mathematica.  There is a problem with the encoding of your file. I cannot open it using UTF-8 encoding with any text editor. Can you?

Comment: CSV/Table import has been rewritten (and much improved!) in 11.2.  It seems it is simply less tolerant of invalid input.

Comment: @Szabolcs: Yes, I can. No problem on my Mac with numbers, Excel, Textedit, all works

Comment: @mgamer Well, I tried all these three and none can interpret your file as UTF8. Sorry, but this file is damaged.  These are not the right programs to try though because they try too hard to be "user-friendly" and they will *silently* ignore errors and interpret the file whatever way they can.  I do not think that either `GÌ¦ring` or `G̦ring` are the desired interpretations though (two things I get from two different text editors)

Comment: @Szabolcs: Thanks for the fast feedback, I´ll also report this to the contributor of "my" data. You´re right with the "luserfriendlyness" of these programs. Maybe this is a source of error here ....

Comment: @mgamer What is the expected form of that word? Is it Göring?  It is possible that there is only one tiny encoding error at the beginning of the file that throws off the interpretation of all the rest. I was trying to figure out a fix along those lines, but I have not been successful yet.

Comment: @Szabolcs: The person is "Katrin Göring-Eckhard" form the Germany party "Die Grünen". The data comes as an CSV (Excel) File from an original JSON source. Maybe on the way to me something got broken. But as mentioned: everything fine with 11.1.1 :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66187/discussion-between-szabolcs-and-mgamer).